# Spring Batch - Unable to deserialize the execution context - OffsetDateTime - cannot deserialize

Tags: serialization, jackson, spring-batch, datetimeoffset, localdate

I'm trying to create a spring batch job with multiples steps and passing object from step to step.
To do this I use ExecutionContext that i promoted from step to job context.
At first run, no problem data goes right from step to step

At next runs, I get the error :
"Unable to deserialize the execution context" Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.OffsetDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

I write context in a ItemWriter like so :

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends Employee> items) throws Exception {
    ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    List<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    e.addAll(items);
    stepContext.put("someKey", e);
}
```

And read it back in a ItemReader (from another step) with :

```
@BeforeStep
public void retrieveInterstepData(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
    this.someObject = (List<Employee>) jobContext.get("someKey");
}
```

I check spring database context and my dates (LocalDate, OffsetDateTime, ...) are store like :

```
"LocalDate": {
    "year": 2019,
    "month": "OCTOBER",
    "dayOfMonth": 30,
    "monthValue": 10,
    "era": ["java.time.chrono.IsoEra", "CE"],
    "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
    "dayOfYear": 303,
    "leapYear": false,
    "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
    }
}
"OffsetDateTime": {
    "offset": {
        "totalSeconds": 0,
        "id": "Z",
        "rules": {
            "fixedOffset": true,
            "transitionRules": ["java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList", []],
            "transitions": ["java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList", []]
        }
    },
    "month": "OCTOBER",
    "year": 2019,
    "dayOfMonth": 28,
    "hour": 13,
    "minute": 42,
    "monthValue": 10,
    "nano": 511651000,
    "second": 36,
    "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
    "dayOfYear": 301
}
```

I guess it's jackson's choice to store it like that (I custom nothing)
But it seems that jackson can't read it's own format at next run ?!

My stubs are generated with from swagger with "swagger-codegen-maven-plugin" and configOptions/dateLibrary=java8 so I can't change them.

I tried to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

And

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
}
```

In the @SpringBootApplication
no change

Any ideas ? Either to store dates more simply like "2019-11-04" or make jackson read it's own format ?

Answer (score 3):

Your object mapper should be set on the `Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer` used by the job repository. You can extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and override `createJobRepository`:

```
@Bean
public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

    Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer defaultSerializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
    defaultSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setSerializer(defaultSerializer);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**
My bad I just saw that I have a

```
@Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
}
```

That provide 2 batchConfigurer to spring.
Thanks !

**ORIGINAL :**

Thanks it seems promising.
But I dont find where to extends and use it, on which class.

I have a Batch Class configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatchProperties.class)
public class BatchDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbURL;

    @Bean("batchDataSource")
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(dbURL);
    return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "batchTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager tm = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    tm.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tm;
    }
}
```

And a Class with Job's definition :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ExtractionJobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job creationJob() {
        ...
    }
    [...]
}
```

And the main :

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "..." })
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

What do you think ?
I also read that Spring Batch 4.2.0+ allow for customisation of ObjectMapper in Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer (https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2828)
Is that what you propose ? (I don't find other information)